# Javascript FB.init oauth parameter for October 1st switchover

Tags: oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am wondering if the OAuth parameter in the FB.init call in the Javascript SDK will start defaulting to true after the October 1st deadline. The current documentation wasn't clear on this point. Obviously you can opt-in now by using oauth: true, however if I don't need to make changes to a whole lot of production code then I'd like to avoid it. Currently not including the parameter means OAuth is disabled.

Comment: If anyone is wondering where this is coming from, "Using the latest SDKs (the JavaScript SDK with the oauth:true parameter and the PHP SDK v.3.1.1)." — https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's Monday and I've seen absolutely no changes over the weekend with the facebook API in regards to Oct. 1st deadline.  I'm hesitant to say that facebook was just blowing smoke? By the end of today, we may yet see something:  "We will post an update on the rollout plan on Monday, Oct 3rd (the changes themselves will proceed as planned)."  (from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/570/))